# Specific world joining problem

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My Family has problems joining one of my worlds. Several other worlds of mine are still accessible by all. The problem world's file size is about 400 MB. I can play alone but when others join it freezes my device and stops on their device around the 35% mark of the "creating world" screen. We are all running 0.11.1. I've tried pretty much everything from turning off all fancy graphics to clearing space on all of the devices. We all have about 5 gigs available on each device. Should I try to save the chunks and reload the game or wait till the next update? We've been working on the world for over a year and I don't want to lose everything. Thanks in advance for any advice you may have.

Comment: 400mb is a HUGE size. You'll have to wait to see if it works tho. Also ram can be full too.

Comment: It does seem like it could be a RAM issue for the host. The individual players only have to load a bit of the world, whereas the host would have to have loaded every place every player is in.

Comment: @cloudymusic apologies for the MB/Mb mistake there haha, noob mistake of mine :)